# Paraller foreach in c#

Tags: c#

I am getting index out of range error if i run below code

```
var list=new list<PriceDetails>();
Parallel.ForEach(productResults.Items, productPrices =>
{
    var  priceDetail=new PriceDetails { price=productPrices.prices.firstordefault();}
    list.add(priceDetail);
}
```

Please provide an example which solves above problem-using concurrent?

Comment: This does not make any sense. You create a list of price details, where the price is always the first price of the list. Maybe you can describe what you want to achieve?

Comment: sample code i have written i.e getting price from 1000 prices in loop and assiging to price details object

Comment: @nvoigt He adds *the first price for each product* to the list.  It's the price from a different product each time though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem you are having is `List.Add(` does not support multiple threads using it at the same time. A better solution is just use PLinq to create a `List<PriceDetails>` via its `AsParallel()` and `ToList()` functions.

```
var list = productResults.Items
                 .AsParallel()
                 .Select(productPrices => new PriceDetails { price = productPrices.prices.firstordefault()})
                 .ToList();
```

This code will go through your source collection in parallel, build up your new classes then combine everything in to a list and assign it to the variable.

However, I would test this with and without the `AsParallel()` going parallel does have overhead costs and making a new class is usually a cheap opration. You may find your code running faster without the `AsParallel()` modifier.

Comment: _You may find your code running faster without the AsParallel() modifier._ I would bet a few points on that - this is a good example of where to __not__ use parallel code.

Comment: @TaW I have tested my code with (for loop) and with out AsParallel for 1000 prices and AsParallel is 100 ms faster than normal for loop and of cource this is negligable

Answer (score 7):

`List<T>` is designed under the assumption that it is never accessed from multiple threads at the same time.  it is not safe to manipulate it from multiple threads in parallel.  You'll need to use a different type of data structure that *does* support this, such as something in `System.Collections.Concurrent`.  Well, that or you could just not do this in parallel to begin with.  I don't see any reason to be parallelizing this task in the first place.

Comment: You mean concurrent List? is there any concurrent list in c#?

Comment: There is no concurrent list.  As I said, you probably shouldn't be parallelizing this at all, just do this sequentially, but if you want to do it anyway, you'll need to look through the available collections and see what meets your needs.

Comment: You would probably want to use [ConcurrentBag](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd381779(v=vs.110).aspx) for this. When you are done populating it, there is a ToList method that can convert it back to a list, if that is what you need.

Comment: @AWinkle Actually he probibily should use `var list=new list<PriceDetails>(productResults.Items.Select(productPrices => new PriceDetails { price=productPrices.prices.firstordefault() }));` If he really wanted it to still be parallel throw a `.AsParallel()` between `.Items` and `.Select`.

Comment: @Scott same code you are writing using linq does it solves probelm ?,@Awinkie i will try with concurrent bag and will see any impact on performance -converting to list

Comment: I hadn't thought of that @ScottChamberlain, great answer above too!